# MySQL finding all elements that have the same value in column A but different values in cloumn B

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to SQL and have a question regarding a query.

I have a database with various pictures attached to a product. All these pictures have a prediction. The structure is like this:

```
product_ id    picture_id     prediction   
  1------------pic1.jpg----------type a       
  1------------pic2.jpg----------type b            
  1------------pic3.jpg----------type b            
  2------------pic4.jpg----------type a                  
  2------------pic5.jpg----------type a                   
  2------------pic6.jpg----------type a       
  3------------pic7.jpg----------type c
 ...
```

... so on.

Each pictures is predicted individually and because of that some of the products have contradictory predictions (meaning that on the same products some pictures are predicted type a while others are predcited type b).

I want to filter out all of these products with a query. In other words: I need all product_ids where the predictions for the pictures linked to it are not all the same. In our example I want it only to show me product 1.

I tried some stuff with GROUP BY, but have not yet gotten anywhere near the result that I want.

Thanks for helping,

Cheers

Comment: Why is product 1 shown? It has `type b` for `pic2.jpg` and `pic3.jpg`?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - can you please edit your post to include code examples of the commands that you've tried, and add a simple data set such that commenters can try to produce a solution locally before they answer your question?

Comment: Yes, but pic1.jpg  (which is also linked to product 1) has type a. And so not all of the pictures have the same predcitions (some have type a and some type b). And I want to find all the products where the predcitions for the pictures is not unanimous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT prediction)` to get the number of different predictions. It will be more than 1 for the products with different predictions.

```
SELECT product_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT prediction) > 1
```

Comment: Doesn't that find product_ids with predictions that are all different? That's not the same as not all the same. Or am I looking at it wrong? I used a Having clause like this: having min(prediction) <> max(prediction);

Comment: I thought she said all different, but maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: i meant not all the same as in "not unanimous"... so it is possible there being two (or more) of the same kind as long as one is different. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: Yes, I figured that out and revised my answer. Doesn't it work?